# how to get youtuber video information in youtube api v3..?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i am working on a youtube based api website and want to get the complete information of a video.
i am doing this as

```
<?php $JSON_Data = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/9Xhat18gkLw?v=2&alt=json")); ?>
```

and getting data using this method

```
channel is:<?php echo $JSON_Data->entry->author[0]->name->{'$t'}."<br>"; ?>description is:<?php echo $JSON_Data->entry->{'media$description'}->$t."<br>"; ?>published time:<?php echo $JSON_Data->entry->published->{'$t'}."<br>"; ?>duration time:<?php echo $JSON_Data->{'yt$duration'}->seconds."<br>"; ?>image link:<?php echo $JSON_Data->{'media$thumbnail'}[2]->url."<br>"; ?>title is:<?php echo $JSON_Data->entry->title->{'$t'}."<br>"; ?>
```

but i am successful in getting a few information like title, channel name and published time

**channel is:Naatsworld**

**description is:**

**published time:2011-08-27T01:32:36.000Z**

**duration time:**

**image link:**

**title is:Owais Raza Qadri - Main So Jaon Ya Mustafa Kehte Kehte (Full Video Naat Album)!!!**

i also want to get video duration, description and image link
please help me how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps you lot :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function youtubeFeedCallback(data) {
    document.writeln('<img src="' + data.entry["media$group"]["media$thumbnail"][0].url + '" width="' + data.entry["media$group"]["media$thumbnail"][0].width + '" height="' + data.entry["media$group"]["media$thumbnail"][0].height + '" alt="Default Thumbnail" align="right"/>');
    document.writeln('<b>Title:</b> ' + data.entry["title"].$t + '<br/>');
    document.writeln('<b>Author:</b> ' + data.entry["author"][0].name.$t + '<br/>');
    document.writeln('<b>Published:</b> ' + new Date(data.entry["published"].$t.substr(0, 4), data.entry["published"].$t.substr(5, 2) - 1, data.entry["published"].$t.substr(8, 2)).toLocaleDateString() + '<br/>');
    document.writeln('<b>Duration:</b> ' + Math.floor(data.entry["media$group"]["yt$duration"].seconds / 60) + ':' + (data.entry["media$group"]["yt$duration"].seconds % 60) + ' (' + data.entry["media$group"]["yt$duration"].seconds + ' seconds)<br/>');
    document.writeln('<b>Rating:</b> ' + new Number(data.entry["gd$rating"].average).toFixed(1) + ' out of ' + data.entry["gd$rating"].max + '; ' + data.entry["gd$rating"].numRaters + ' rating(s)' + '<br/>');
    document.writeln('<b>Statistics:</b> ' + data.entry["yt$statistics"].favoriteCount + ' favorite(s); ' + data.entry["yt$statistics"].viewCount + ' view(s)' + '<br/>');
    document.writeln('<br/>' + data.entry["media$group"]["media$description"].$t.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') + '<br/>');
    document.writeln('<br/><a href="' + data.entry["media$group"]["media$player"].url + '" target="_blank">Watch on YouTube</a>');
}
</script>
```

[View demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/aCd8s/)

Comment: i want to do this in php please tell me how to do this in php